# Duplicate Keys Desktop Hybris SmartEdit error

Tags: upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

We have recently migrated from Hybris 6.4 to 1905 version and have setup smartedit . We are getting the below exception on opening homepage inside smartedit.

There is no error on console . However the homepage view is filled with red boxes

[image]

Can anyone please help as to what could be causing these ?

Comment: I noticed that you want to hide the company for which you are building the Website. I believe you forgot to hide the text under the "NEW FOR YOU" header which tells us the information you are trying to hide

Comment: You can try to investigate the issue by creating an Exception Breakpoint which will halt the execution when the exception is thrown. That way you can see where the exception is thrown and you can try to understand why